# Python: How do you use re to ignore links in parentheses?

Tags: python, regex

The relevant part of the code is:

```
import re
reargs = '<a\s*href=[\'|"](.*?)[\'"].*?>'
link = re.search(reargs,content,flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

I'm building a crawler and the web pages I'm working with have links in parentheses that I don't want so it would be like:

Foo foo foo foo (*link*) foo foo foo foo *link* foo foo foo foo (foo *link* foo) foo foo *link* foo foo *link*......and so on

Comment: Don't use RegEx to parse HTML.  Use an (X)HTML Parser.  BeautifulSoup comes to mind.

Comment: [Parsing HTML/XML with regexes can be problematic.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/1732454#1732454)

Comment: To add just a hint more detail, while it is possible with modern regular expressions to do things like you're asking, it generally isn't the best idea. A good clue that you should be using some different technology is the fact that you're trying to match balanced parenthesis and have the possibility for nested items.

Answer (score 0):

If there can be multiple sets of nested parentheses like "((foo) *link*)", I don't think this is possible with regular expressions. In particular, note that parentheses can be used inside URLs (such as at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29)), so there may still be nested parens even if the text itself doesn't contain any. So, in the general case I don't think this can be done with regex.

In order to solve it, I will assume you can have parentheses at most 1 level deep, and that no URLs contain parentheses.

The regex you're looking for is something like the following:

```
(\([^\)]*\)|[^\(<])*_link_
```

Where `_link_` is a regular expression matching a link (which you describe in the problem statement, though it might need some tweaking). To summarize what that first part of my regex is: it matches 0 or more of either a parenthetical statement or a non-link non-parenthesis character. Now, use the matched back references (`link.group(2)` in your example) to find your URL.

Answer (score 0):

In general parsing HTML with regex is a bad idea. But because you asked, and the general question has merit (how to ignore cases where your match is surrounded by parentheses) I'll tell you what I think.

Now, because I don't know what your page looks like I'll just say that, in general, you can exclude matches by adding `[^x]`,except where `x` is the character you don't want. The brackets make it so that it will match anything, and the `^` excludes whatever follows.

So you can exclude parentheses by surround your match string with `[^(]`foo`[^)]`. If there are other characters between the parentheses you'll have to account for that separately.

Answer (score 0):

With [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/) you could do something like this:

```
import lxml.html
import re

tree = lxml.html.parse("http://pastehtml.com/view/b7604in99.html")
links = tree.xpath("//a")

for link in links:
    if re.match(r'^\(.*\)$', link.text.strip()):
        print link.get('href')
```